# How can I store and retrieve form values as data in local storage, and then display them in the UI?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, local-storage, rendering, key-value-store

I want to store the input values from a user, that is its name, age and gender to local storage and then display it to UI.

What happens right now is that after displaying a newly registered student at the UI and storing the data locally (which both works) but then reloading the page the student data disappears from the UI. I don't want this to happen; how do I go about it?

This is some of the code I came up with so far ...

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">

    <h1>student's info</h1>

    <form class="input-form">
      <input type="text"class="full-name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Full Name">
      <input type="number"class="age" name="name" placeholder="Age">
      <input type="text" class = "gender"name="name" placeholder="gender">
      <button class="submit-btn" type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="con"> 
    <div class="student">
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

```js
// GLOBAL VARIABLES
var submitBtn, student, fullName, age, gender;

submitBtn = document.querySelector('.submit-btn');
student = document.querySelector('.student');
fullName = document.querySelector('.full-name');
age = document.querySelector('.age');
gender = document.querySelector('.gender');

var arr = [];

// EVENTLISTENERS
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', addStudent);

// FUNCTIONS
function addStudent(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('student-box');

  let nameSpan = document.createElement('span');
  nameSpan.classList.add('student-name');
  nameSpan.innerText = fullName.value;

  let ageSpan = document.createElement('span');
  ageSpan.classList.add('student-age');
  ageSpan.innerText = age.value;

  let genderSpan = document.createElement('span');
  genderSpan.classList.add('student-gender');
  genderSpan.innerText = gender.value;

  saveToLocal();

  div.append(nameSpan, ageSpan, genderSpan);

  student.appendChild(div);

  fullName.value = '';
  age.value = '';
  gender.value = '';
}

function saveToLocal() {
  getData();

  arr.push({
    name: fullName.value,
    ages: age.value,
    genders: gender.value,
  });
  localStorage.setItem('student', JSON.stringify(arr));
}

function getData() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('student') !== null) {

    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('student'));

    //localStorage.setItem('student', JSON.stringify(arr));
    //var dis = JSON.Parse(localStorage.getItem('student'));
    //student.appendChild();
    //arr = JSON.parse();
    //console.log(arr);

  }/* else {

  }*/
}
```

Comment: on page load get values from localstorage

Comment: @AzongoIsmail ... From all the so far provided approaches / solutions are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the student object from local storage and then use the values to set your input values like this:

```js
if(localStorage.getItem('student') !== null) {
    try {
      const studentData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('student'))[0];
      fullName = studentData.name;
      age = studentData.age;
      gender = studentData.gender;
      document.getElementsByClassName("full-name")[0].value = fullName;
      document.getElementsByClassName("age")[0].value = age;
      document.getElementsByClassName("gender")[0].value = gender;
    } catch() {}
}
```

Comment: it showing undefined value in full-name this textbox, please check some mistake

Comment: It's not the full code. It's just the part that reads values from local storage and then set the input values.

Comment: code is good, i am not saying full code,  as you given [0] for getElementsByClassName , i suggest   above line also require like this studentData[0].name  .  try on your end . i think like this.

Answer (score 0):

From the OP's code it becomes clear that the OP wants ...

- to retrieve from the [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) the entire student related data as **an array of student specific data-items**.
- to add a ***single* new student** at time via ***each* form submit**.
- for each form-submit ...

  - ... to create a new data-item which then ...

    - ... has to be added (pushed) to the initially retrieved list of already registered students ...
    - ... where this updated/mutated array then in its entirety has to be saved/put into the `localStorage` again.
  - ... to create a new DOM-fragment (view-item) which contains all of the newly registered student's data  which then ...

    - ... has to be appended to the initially rendered DOM representation of all yet registered students.

Thus the OP will need to implement at least one specialized and properly named function (there will be additional helper functions as well) for each above mentioned task.

Let's start with the storage; one wants to do both get and put the entire registered student data from and into the local storage. Therefore one is going to implement two functions `getRegisteredStudentData` and `putRegisteredStudentData`. Whereas the latter is easy for it straightforwardly stores a JSON-stringified version of an array of student related data-items, the former already adds complexity because one has to assure the validity of the retrieved data. In terms of registered students this means **an array of *unique* data-items**.

In order to assure uniqueness one has to first create a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instance where one would add each data item via an item's key where the key is created from an item's data values, here the [concatenated values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) of (full-)`name`, `gender` and `age`. Then one returns the array representative of all of the created map's unique [`values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values).

The above two paragraph's are the description of the two helper tasks `sanitizeRegisteredStudentData`  and `createMapOfUniqueStudentItems`. Another helper is `parseJSON` which implements [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) functionality which does not throw exceptions.

Another task is the rendering of all of the stored and retrieved student data. A function named `renderRegisteredStudentData` would expect two parameters, the DOM/element-node of where the created student overview should be appended to (`dataParent`) and the array of student items (`studentList`).

There are repetitive tasks of element-node creation which can be implemented as functions itself e.g. the creation of a single registered student's view from a data-item's `name`, `gender` and `age` properties. Thus `createRegisteredStudentViewItem` is a re-usable render helper.

What is still left are the initialization of ...

1. ... when and where to render the initially retrieved stored student data.
2. ... the `'submit'`-type event registration and the handling for whenever a new student's data item is going to be created, pushed/stored and rendered/appended.

As for **(1)**, within the initialization task one would query the
element-node where one wants to append the rendered student data to. One also needs to retrieve the student list which gets achieved by invoking `getRegisteredStudentData`. Since all render tasks are already implemented one just needs to invoke `renderRegisteredStudentData`, passing the node and the array of data-items to it.

As for **(2)**, within the initialization task one additionally would query the form-element-node as well in order to [add an event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Whenever a new student gets registered via form-`'submit'` one wants a handler function to take care of the following ...

- [preventing the actual form default action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).
- creation of a data-item from the form's current [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries).
- accessing all necessary and [bound](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), registry specific, contextual data from the handler function's `this`-context ... which is ...

  ```
  const { dataRoot, studentList, studentMap } = this;
  ```

  - `dataRoot` is needed in order to have a reference into the DOM structure where a newly rendered student's view-item should be appended to.
  - `studentList` is the reference of the array of data-items where one wants to push/add the newly created data-item in/to.
  - `studentMap` is the reference of mapped unique data-items one needs as lookup in order to not allow the creation of registered student duplicates.
- assuring the uniqueness of the newly created data-item and then ...

  - updating both, the student list/array ([`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)) and the student lookup map ([`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set))
  - a local [storage update](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) with the just updated/mutated student list.
  - rendering/appending of the newly registered student's data.

***Note** ... since SO prevents the usage of `localStorage` the beneath provided example code gets shipped with a mocked implementation of locale storage functionality which means that registered student data does not survive a page reload.*

```js
function parseJSON(value) {
  let result;
  try { result = JSON.parse(String(value)); } catch (err) {}
  return result;
}

function createMapOfUniqueStudentItems(studentList) {
  return new Map(
    studentList
      .map(({ name, gender, age }) => [
        // create any student's unique key for a map ...
        [name.toLowerCase(), gender.toLowerCase(), age].join('_'),
        // ... of unique student items.
        { name, gender, age }
      ])
  );
}
function sanitizeRegisteredStudentData(studentList) {
  return Array.isArray(studentList)
    && [
      // get rid of possible duplicate data items.
      ...createMapOfUniqueStudentItems(studentList).values()
    ] || [];
}

function getRegisteredStudentData() {
  return sanitizeRegisteredStudentData(
    parseJSON(
      localStorage
        .getItem('registered-students')
    )
  );
}
function putRegisteredStudentData(value) {
  return localStorage
    .setItem('registered-students', JSON.stringify(value));
}

function createRegisteredStudentViewItem({ name, gender, age }) {
  return [name, gender, age]
    .reduce((itemRoot, value) => {
    
      const valueNode = document.createElement('td');
      valueNode.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(value)
      );
      itemRoot.appendChild(valueNode);

      return itemRoot;

    }, document.createElement('tr'));
}
function renderRegisteredStudentData(dataParent, studentList) {
  console.log({ get: studentList });

  const dataRoot = (new DOMParser)
    .parseFromString(
      '<table><thead></thead><tbody></tbody></table>',
      "text/html",
    )
    .querySelector('table')
    .cloneNode(true);

  dataRoot
    .querySelector('thead')
    .appendChild(createRegisteredStudentViewItem({
      name: 'Full Name', gender: 'Gender', age: 'Age',
    }));

  studentList
    .reduce((itemParent, studentData) => {

      itemParent.appendChild(
        createRegisteredStudentViewItem(studentData)
      );
      return itemParent;

    }, dataRoot.querySelector('tbody'));

  dataParent.appendChild(dataRoot);
}

function registerNewStudentFromBoundContext(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  const { dataRoot, studentList, studentMap } = this;

  const formData = new FormData(evt.currentTarget);
  const itemData = [
    ...formData.entries()
  ]
  .reduce((result, [key, value]) =>
    Object.assign(result, { [ key ]: value }), {}
  );
  const { name, gender, age } = itemData;

  // create a student items unique key for a map lookup.
  const uniqueStudentKey = [
    name.toLowerCase(), gender.toLowerCase(), age
  ].join('_');

  // prevent duplicates.
  if (!studentMap.has(uniqueStudentKey)) {

    // add non duplicate item data to list or registered students ...
    studentList.push(itemData);

    // ... update the lookup map accordingly ...
    studentMap.set(uniqueStudentKey, itemData);

    // ... and update the local storage.
    putRegisteredStudentData(studentList);

    console.log({ put: studentList });

    // render the newly registered student's data.
    dataRoot
      .querySelector('tbody') 
      .appendChild(
        createRegisteredStudentViewItem(itemData)
      );
  }
}

function initStudentRegistry(rootNode) {
  const formNode = rootNode.querySelector('form');
  const overviewNode = rootNode.querySelector('.registry-overview');

  const studentList = getRegisteredStudentData();
  const studentMap = createMapOfUniqueStudentItems(studentList);

  renderRegisteredStudentData(overviewNode, studentList);

  formNode
    .addEventListener(
      'submit', registerNewStudentFromBoundContext.bind({
        dataRoot: overviewNode, studentList, studentMap,
      }),
    );

  // additional helpers for local storage 
  // related demonstration purposes only.

  formNode
    .querySelector('[data-clear-table]')
    .addEventListener('click', evt => {
      evt.preventDefault();

      [...overviewNode.querySelector('tbody').childNodes]
        .forEach(child => child.remove());
    });
  formNode
    .querySelector('[data-rerender-table]')
    .addEventListener('click', evt => {
      evt.preventDefault();

      [...overviewNode.childNodes]
        .forEach(child => child.remove());

      renderRegisteredStudentData(
        overviewNode, getRegisteredStudentData(),
      );
    });
}

function main() {
  initStudentRegistry(
    document
      .querySelector('.student-registry')
  );
}
main();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
form, h1 { position: fixed; right: 45%; }
h1 { margin: 0; font-size: 1.2em;  width: 7.9em; } 
form { top: 1.5em;  width: 9.5em; }
table { width: 30%; margin: 0; }
fieldset { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none; }
button { margin: 4px 0; }
fieldset button { display: block; }
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; min-height: 100%; width: 45%; }
```

```html
<script>
  // mock for the SO specific stack snippet
  // due to the policies and environment are
  // not allowing an original storage access.
  const localStorage = (function () {

    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map
    const storage = new Map;

    function key(int) {
      return [
        ...storage.keys()
      ][parseInt(int, 10)];
    }

    function setItem(key, value) {
      return storage.set(String(key), String(value));
    }
    function getItem(key) {
      return storage.get(String(key));
    }

    function removeItem(key) {
      return storage.delete(String(key));
    }

    function clear() {
      return storage.clear();
    }

    return {
      get length() {
        return storage.size;
      },
      key,
      getItem,
      setItem,
      removeItem,
      clear,      
    };

  }());
</script>

<main>
  <div class="student-registry">
    <h1>student's info</h1>

    <form method="post" action="">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Full Name"/>
      <input type="number" name="age" placeholder="Age" value="6" min="6" max="120"/>
      <input type="text" name="gender" placeholder="Gender"/>

      <button type="submit">
        register student
      </button>

      <fieldset>
        <button data-clear-table>
          clear table
        </button>
        <button data-rerender-table>
          rerender table<br/>from (mocked)<br/>local storage
        </button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>

    <div class="con"> 
      <div class="registry-overview">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score -1):

as your data is storing to localstorage so try like below,

```js
document.getElementById("buttotton").onclick = function() {  
fun()  
};  
function fun()
{
  var arr = [];
        arr.push({
            name:document.getElementsByClassName("full-name")[0].value,
            ages:"25",
            genders:"male"
    
        });
        localStorage.setItem('student', JSON.stringify(arr));
}
if(localStorage.getItem('student') !== null) {

  let text = localStorage.getItem("student");
  const obj = JSON.parse(text);
   // const studentData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('student'));
    fullName = obj[0].name;
     
 
    document.getElementsByClassName("full-name")[0].value = fullName;
    
  
}
```

```html
<input type="text"class="full-name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Full Name">
<input type="button" id="buttotton" value="save">
```

Comment: Your code is wrong. we can't set innerHTML on HTMLCollection.
And also it's better to set input value with .value not .innerHTML.
Just another point is that the strudent data in localstorage is an object.

Comment: try again i made some changes